# Excel Services permissions error

Tags: 2010, excel-services

I have created a document library, and gotten that library added to the Excel Services Trusted Locations in central admin.  I’m using an account which has full control on the document library to connect, and I’m trying to connect to an XLSX that has all of its worksheets accessible to Excel Services.

The error I receive is “Error querying Excel Services. You do not have permissions to open this file.”  All my googling indicates this problem is solved by adding the document library to the trusted locations list.

My problem is that adding the document library to the trusted locations list didn't solve my problem.  Anything else I can do?

I have confirmed that I can open the spreadsheet in the browser, and I have also opened it via web part.